# Comment Field, 'Your Name,' Will Not Accept Un-Registered Names

Tags: 7, users, comments

We want anonymous users to be able to leave comments with their **names**. However, even though I've set anonymous commenting on the appropriate content type to 'Anonymous posters *must* leave their contact information' (I've also tried "may leave...), when entering a value in the Your Name field, it will not accept it.

When it is a required field, it gives an error, "Your name field is required," anytime there is a value entered other than an existing user name.

Does anyone know how to allow anonymous users to leave their name?

Comment: Do you have other modules modify the user or comment form/process (e.g. Real Name module)? By default, D7 core comments allows you to place any arbitrary name anonymously, [_unless it's a preexisting username_](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/comment/comment.module?h=7.x#n2141).

Comment: We use the [Comment Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_notify) module version 7.x-1.3. That's the only contributed module I see which requires the Core Comment module. I can't find a way in which it could be causing this, but our instance of Drupal definitely isn't accepting an arbitrary name. It will actually _only_ take pre-existing usernames. So it's kind of functioning backwards as of right now...

Comment: Odd. The only thing I can think of is `hook_form_alter()` invocation using Devel's `dpm()` on `$form['#validate']` to see if any other validation handlers are doing this. Either that, or searching the code base for "Your name field is required" to see where that validation logic is being applied.